# I'm trying to deploy on vercel with express and mongo.db, but is giving error 504: GATEWAY_TIMEOUT

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

**This is the database.js code**

```
import { MongoClient } from "mongodb";

// Replace the uri string with your connection string.
const user = encodeURIComponent("***")
const password = encodeURIComponent("***")
const uri = `mongodb+srv://${user}:${password}@cluster0.svj6inc.mongodb.net/`;
export const client = new MongoClient(uri);

const database = client.db('to_do_list');
const collection = database.collection('lista_de_afazeres');

export async function create(nome, descricao, feito){
    const doc = {
        nome: `${nome}`,
        descricao: `${descricao}`,
        feito: feito
    }

    const result = await collection.insertOne(doc)
    console.log(`O documento foi inserido com o _id: ${result.insertedId}`);

}

export async function readAll(){
    // const cursor = collection.find({_id: {$lt: 0}})
    const cursor = collection.find({})
    // Convert the cursor to an array
    const documents = await cursor.toArray();

    // Print returned documents
    return documents;
}

export async function readOneByName(nome){
    const cursor = await collection.findOne({nome:nome})
    return cursor
}

export async function updateByName(nome, alteracao1, alteracao2, alteracao3){
    const filter = {nome: nome}
    const updateName = {
        $set : {
            nome: alteracao1,
            descricao: alteracao2,
            feito: alteracao3
        }
    }
    const result = await collection.updateOne(filter, updateName)
    return result
}

export async function deleteByName(nome){
    const query = {nome : nome}
    const result = await collection.deleteOne(query)
    return result
}

async function run() {
  try {
    await client.connect()
  } finally {
    // Ensures that the client will close when you finish/error
    await client.close();
  }
}

run().catch(console.dir);
```

**It's my server.js code:**

```
import express from 'express'
import cors from 'cors'
import {client, create, readAll, readOneByName, updateByName, deleteByName} from '../infra/database.js'

export const app = express()
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000

// O express começará a ler as requisições req.body no formato de json
app.use(express.json())
app.use(cors())


app.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        await client.connect()
        await create(req.body.nome, req.body.descricao, req.body.feito)
        res.status(201).send("Cadastro feito com sucesso!")
    } catch (error){
        console.dir
    }
})

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        await client.connect()
        res.status(200).send(await readAll())
    } catch (error) {
        console.dir
    }
})

app.get('/:nome', async (req,res) =>{
    try {
        await client.connect()
        res.status(200).send(await readOneByName(req.params.nome))
    } catch (error) {
        console.dir
    }
})

app.put('/:nome', async (req, res) =>{
    try {
        await client.connect()
        await updateByName(req.params.nome, req.body.nome, req.body.descricao, req.body.feito)
        res.status(200).send("Alteração feita com sucesso")
        } catch (error) {
        console.dir
    }
})

app.delete('/:nome', async (req, res) =>{
    try {
        await client.connect()
        await deleteByName(req.params.nome)
        res.status(200).send("Apagou atividade com sucesso!")
    } catch (error) {
        console.dir
    }
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

**Its my vercel.json code:**

```
{
  "name": "controlador-de-gastos",
  "public": true,
  "version": 2,
  "builds":[
      {
          "src": "src/server.js",
          "use": "@vercel/node"
      }
  ],
  "routes": [
      {
          "src": "/(.*)",
          "dest": "src/server.js"
      }
  ]
}
```

**Its my package.json code:**

```
{
  "name": "to-do-list-mongo-db",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "<h1>Passos para fazer as instalações corretamente:</h1>\r <ol>\r     <li>nmp init -y</li>\r     <li>npm install express --save</li>\r     <li></li>\r     <li></li>\r </ol>",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "engines": {
    "node": "18.x"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon ./src/server.js",
    "start": "node ./src/server.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "mongodb": "6.3",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.18.2"
  }
}
```

i dont know why its happens on vercel, because i already added the integrations on my api:

This Serverless Function has timed out.

Your connection is working correctly.

Vercel is working correctly.

504: GATEWAY_TIMEOUT
Code: FUNCTION_INVOCATION_TIMEOUT
ID: gru1::6nd42-1702133783065-45ea92387b40